# how do i replace dynamically product names with static values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, replace

how do i replace dynamically product names with static values im getting all products names from database but i want to create function that will replace some words in the product names after fetching all records from database.

**for example**

"Zon Stock" is a product name which is fetched from database, and i want system to replace only `Stock` and should'nt replace `Zon Stock`  completed product name

**problem**

problem is that i have code that is working fine but only working with hard code not working with dynamically records

**Static Code**

```
$a="this is testing script STOCK,stock,Stock";

$replaceWord=array("

STOCK " =>  "UAE PRODUCTS",
"stock" => "uae products",  
"Stock" => "Uae Products");

$new_test= strtr($a, $replaceWord);

echo $new_test;
```

but same code is not working with `product name field` fetched from database

```
$query=mysql_query("select pnames from products order by pid asc");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

$a = $row['pnames'];

$replaceWord=array("

STOCK " =>  "UAE PRODUCTS",
"stock" => "uae products",  
"Stock" => "Uae Products");

$new_test= strtr($a, $replaceWord);

echo $new_test;


}
```

**thank you i have completed my script here**

```
here my script

$query=mysql_query("select pnames from products order by pid asc");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);

$a=$row['pnames'];

$replaceWord=array(
$a="STOCK" =>  "UAE DUBAI",
$a="stock" => "uae dubai",  
$a="Stock" => "Uae Dubai");

echo $new_row['Name'] =     strtr($row['pnames'], $replaceWord);
```

Comment: you sure you mean strstr? Not str_replace?

Comment: is `$row['pnames']` a string like `$a="this is testing script STOCK,stock,Stock";` ??

Comment: [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) extension is officially deprecated as of php 5.5 and will be removed, therefore switch to alternatives. *see the red notice*

Comment: @code-jaff thanks this is just sample coding but in real im using bigcommerce shopping cart

Comment: @khalid yes exactly i want to replace `$row['pnames']` to string like `$a`

Comment: but what is `$row['pnames']` please try `var_dump($row['pnames']);` and post the result

Comment: `$row['pnames']` is db field or column

Comment: i mean where ever `stock` fetch from db in `$row['pnames']` system should be replace that word into `UAE PRODUCTS`

Comment: my working but only for static values not working for dynamically columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of ...

```
$query = mysql_query("select pnames from products order by pid asc");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

  $a = $row['pnames'];

  // for simplicity I'm using function here
  $get_result = word_replace($a);

}

function word_replace($key) {

 // array of static words
 $replaceWord = array(
  "STOCK " =>  "UAE PRODUCTS",
  "stock" => "uae products",  
  "Stock" => "Uae Products"
 );

 // Find in array
 if (array_key_exists($key, $replaceWord)) {

  // replace that string
  $replace_string = $replaceWord[$key];

 } else {
  $replace_string = $key;
 }
 return $replace_string;
}
```

May be this one helpful to you.

Comment: Farhan please try to dubug the code. May be your problem will sort out. I also faced that issue but that code helpful to me.